# Change date format in Meteor publication

Tags: meteor

I need to change the date format in a publication and am wondering if its possible in Meteor. I'd ideally like to do this:

```
Meteor.publish('foo', function () {
   var user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.userId});
   if (user) {
      var f = Foos.find({organizationId: user.profile.organizationId})
      return f.map(function(cx) { cx.createdAt = moment.utc(cx.createdAt).format(); return cx });
   }

   return [];
});
```

But if I do this I get the following exception:

```
Exception from sub 2 Error: Publish function returned an array of non-Cursors
```

Answer (score 0):

You're better off letting the publication send the date natively and changing the format on the client.

Check out the `transform` option of Mongo collections, or of collection.`find` - http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find

```js
Foos.find(
  {...}, 
  {
    transform: function (doc) {
      doc.createdAt = moment.utc(doc.createdAt).format();
      return doc;
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Do you think that will mess up mini-mongo on the client?

Comment: No, not at all. Minimongo is agnostic of the nature of dates. You should still be able to sort, for example.